# I would like to check in prolog if one list has the same elements

Tags: list, prolog

I would like to write in prolog "check if one list has the same elements" e.g list[a,a,a,a]  is true. list[a,c,a,a] is false.
How can I do so?

Comment: I think you have a similar issue here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408310/prolog-element-is-a-list-member-check

Comment: no this is not the same issue. i would like to check if one list has all elements same. thanks e.g list[a,a,a,a] is true.

Comment: If you solved your problem consider closing this question marking the answer with the sticky, as accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now that I understood the request whats about this:

```
compare([X|Y]):-help(Y,X).
compare([]).

help([],_).
help([Y|X],Y) :- help(X,Y).
```

Comment: You can get the last line even shorter using pattern matching: `help([Y|X],Y) :- help(X,Y).`

Comment: `compare(X)` will start enumerating with `X = [_]`, `X = [_,_]`... but `X = []` will not be produced which is a bit unintuitive.

Comment: sure, but I think it doesn't need to. the recursion is in help, not in compare. The compare([]) kind of base case is just so the empty list gets accepted as well.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with one, simple predicate:

```
same([]).   % You only need this one if you want the empty list to succeed
same([_]).
same([X,X|T]) :- same([X|T]).
```

Results:

```
| ?- same([a,b,a,a]).

no
| ?- same([a,a,a,a]).

true ? ;

no
| ?- same([]).

yes
```

**ADDENDUM 1**

Changing the order of the clauses so that the base cases are first allows:

```
| ?- same(L).

L = [] ? ;

L = [_] ? ;

L = [A,A] ? ;

L = [A,A,A] ? ;
...
```

**ADDENDUM 2**

Another approach, using DCG, might be:

```
same(_) --> [].
same(X) --> [X], same(X).
```

Then:

```
| ?- phrase(same(_), [a,b,a,a]).

no
| ?- phrase(same(_), [a,a,a,a]).

true ? a

(1 ms) no
| ?- phrase(same(X), L).

L = [] ? ;

L = [X] ? ;

L = [X,X] ? ;

L = [X,X,X] ? ;
...
```

Comment: +1 for the best recursive answer so far.

Comment: 1mo: Does it make sense to produce no answer for `same(L)`? 2do: Many systems are not able to execute this efficiently, since indexing does not go that deep. So `same/1` will create *n* choicepoints....

Comment: @false - thanks and very good points. For `same(L)` I changed the order of the clauses. I'll need to think about your second point further.

Answer (score 3):

```
same(L) :-
   maplist(=(_),L).

?- maplist(=(_),L).
   L = []
;  L = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_A,_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_A,_A,_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_A,_A,_A,_A]
;  ... .
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868).

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in [list_to_set/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=lists%3alist_to_set/2), this can be done in a single line:

```
?- list_to_set([a,a,a,a],[_]).
true.

?- list_to_set([a,a,c,a],[_]).
false.
```

The conversion of a list to a set removes duplicates.. so if you are left with a list that can be unified to one item [_], then there are no duplicates.

If the list has duplicates, there will be > 1 item in the set, and the [_] predicate unification will fail.

This obviously won't work on an empty list - a separate rule will be needed for that.

Comment: But removing duplicates costs as much as sorting, that is O(*n* ld *n*) instead of the necessary O(*n*).